# STL priority queue with duplicate keys - is it possible?

Tags: c++, stl

I need to store my class A objects in some data structure.
In addition, i would like them to be automatically sorted according to a key, which is in my case an embedded object of another class B.

Thus I decided to use a STL priority queue.

However it is possible that the 2 or more objects B to have the same key value.

My questions:

**Does the STL  priority queue allow duplicate keys??**

**If it does what should I consider and which predicate should I use?**

**I know I could use a multiset but its Big O notation performance is worse, that why I want to use the priority queue.**

Answer (score 19):

> Does the STL priority queue allow duplicate keys??

Yes: [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) puts no limitations on the values of the keys.

> If it does what should I consider

The order between equal elements may change arbitrarily, so you cannot rely on a particular order of elements with identical keys.

> and which predicate should I use?

This will depend on your required semantics. In general, you need to provide a type that fulfils the [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements; in particular, it needs to be a [strict weak ordering relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). If your type implements `operator<` consistently, then the default comparer (= `std::less<YourType>`) will work out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it supports duplicate keys.

From the doucumentation:

```
void push(const value_type& x) Inserts x into the priority_queue.
                               Postcondition: size() will be incremented by 1.
```

A simple test confirms it:

```
int main() {
  priority_queue<int> q;
  q.push(5);
  q.push(5);
  cout << q.top() << endl;
  q.pop();
  cout << q.top() << endl;
  q.pop();
}
```

Outputs:

```
5
5
```

As for the predicate, use whatever you would have used before - nothing guaranteed by the priority queue is broken by allowing equal elements, so your algorithm should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Konrad has a great answer. To add to that, you should know that `priority_queue` doesn't necessarily have great performance. According to this page [http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/classstd_1_1priority__queue.html](http://www.cs.brown.edu/%7Ejwicks/libstdc++/html_user/classstd_1_1priority__queue.html), it looks like it is implemented by doing a `make_heap`, `pop_heap`, etc... on all operations to get the highest priority.

The re-heapifying, can be expensive compared to other data structures, depending on your use case.

Comment: From what I learned in Data Structures, that's basically The Way to create priority queues ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Implementation for instance).

Comment: Agreed, I was just pointing out that priority queues aren't necessarily super efficient because he mentioned choosing it because of set's poor performance.